# Why the same function prints different output?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have defined the following module to implement a *matrix* type:

```ml
module MatrixImplementation: MatrixADT.MatrixInterface =
  struct
    type 'a matrix = {n: int; m: int; c: 'a array array};;
    let zeroes n m = {n= n; m= m; c= Array.make_matrix n m 0};;
    let identity n =
      let m = zeroes n n
      in for i = 0 to (n-1) do
        m.c.(i).(i) <- 1
      done;
      (m);
    ;;
    let init n =
      let m = zeroes n n
        in for i = 0 to (n-1)do
          for j = 0 to (n-1) do
            m.c.(i).(j) <- (n-1) * i + j;
          done;
        done;
        (m);
    ;;
    (* . . . *)
    let rec print_row  rl =
      match rl with
      | [] -> print_string("");
      | v::cl -> Format.printf "%2d " v; print_row cl;
    ;;
    let rec print_matrix m =
      match Array.to_list m.c with
      | [] -> print_string("");
      | r::rl ->
        print_string "[ ";
        print_row (Array.to_list r);
        print_string "]\n";
        print_matrix {n= ((m.n)-1); m= (m.m); c= Array.of_list rl};
    ;;
  end;;
```

However when I declare matrices using the module functions (`zeroes`, `identity`, `init`) and try to print them, only part of the lines that compose them are formatted, the first lines are not correctly formatted.

For instance i tried with:

```ml
let empty = zeroes 3 5;;
let id = identity 4;;
let mat = init 5;;

print_matrix mat;;
print_matrix empty;;
print_matrix id;;
```

And I got it as a result:

```
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
[  0  1  2  3  4  4  5  6  7  8  8  9 10 11 12 12 13 14 15 16 16 17 18 19 20  0  0  0  0  0 ]
[  0  0  0  0  0 ]
[  0  0  0  0  0 ]
[  1  0  0  0 ]
[  0  1  0  0 ]
[  0  0  1  0 ]
[  0  0  0  1 ]
```

Comment: You appear to have lots of extraneous `;` and `;;` tokens causing syntax errors. Those should be resolved before moving on. If `MatrixADT.MatrixInterface` is important to understanding this, it should be provided.

Comment: @Chris Even removing the `;` and `;;` does not solve the problem and `MatrixADT.MatrixInterface` is just the signature of the same functions in the module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing the code of my module and its incorrect behavior, the problem is not the way the print functions are defined (leaving out the tricks suggested by @Chris in his answer), but the module used: the `Format` module should be used to make more complex printouts ([API reference](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Format.html)), the formatting error is probably due to the arguments of the `fmt` string; for simpler printing, the `Printf` module and its `printf` function (same arguments) are more suitable.

Therefore a possible change to the printing functions is as follows:

```ml
let rec print_row = function
    | [] -> ()
    | c::cl -> Printf.printf "%2d " c; print_row cl;
and print_matrix m =
    match m.c with
    | [] -> ()
    | rows ->
      for i= 0 to (List.length rows)-1 do
        print_string("[ ");
        print_row (List.nth rows i);
        print_string("]\n");
      done;
;;
```

(In this case the field `c` (content) of type definition `matrix` is `int list list` to avoid conversions)

Answer (score 1):

Stripping your code of unnecessary `;` and `;;` tokens, we can also implement your `print_matrix` function imperatively. Given that you're using arrays, this simply makes more sense.

Converting from arrays to lists and then back so that you can use recursion and pattern matching is both inefficient and makes your code more difficult to understand.

```ml
module MatrixImplementation =
struct
  type 'a matrix = {n : int; m : int; c : 'a array array}
    
  let zeroes n m = {n = n; m = m; c = Array.make_matrix n m 0}
  
  let identity n =
    let m = zeroes n n in 
    for i = 0 to (n-1) do
      m.c.(i).(i) <- 1
    done;
    m
    
  let init n =
    let m = zeroes n n in 
    for i = 0 to (n-1) do
      for j = 0 to (n-1) do
        m.c.(i).(j) <- (n-1) * i + j
      done;
    done;
    m

  let print_matrix {n; m; c} =
    for i = 0 to n - 1 do
      print_string "[";
      for j = 0 to m - 1 do
        Printf.printf " %d " c.(i).(j)
      done;
      print_string "]\n"
    done
end
```

```
utop # MatrixImplementation.(init 3 |> print_matrix);;
[ 0  1  2 ]
[ 2  3  4 ]
[ 4  5  6 ]
- : unit = ()
```

A note: `print_string ""` effectively does nothing. If you need to actually do nothing, you can simply return `()` (unit).

Note also that in `print_matrix` I've used pattern matching right in the function arguments (`let print_matrix {n; m; c} =`) to save myself some time. This could have been written as:

```
  let print_matrix m =
    for i = 0 to m.n - 1 do
      print_string "[";
      for j = 0 to m.m - 1 do
        Printf.printf " %d " m.c.(i).(j)
      done;
      print_string "]\n"
    done
```

We could take advantage of the `Array.iter` function.

```ml
  let print_matrix {n; m; c} =
    Array.(
      let print_row arr =
        print_string "[";
        arr |> iter (Printf.printf " %d ");
        print_string "]\n"
      in
      c |> iter print_row 
    )
```

---

If we consider your original approach, the following will fix it.

```ml
  let rec print_row rl =
    List.iter (Printf.printf " %2d ") rl
```

---

As an added note, we can use the `Format` module to define a custom formatter for an array.

```
let pp_array 
    (type t) (module M : Stringable with type t = t) 
    ?(sep = "; ") 
    ?(start = "[|") 
    ?(fin = "|]") 
    () 
    ppf 
    (arr : t array) =
  Format.fprintf 
    ppf 
    "%s%s%s" 
    start 
    (arr |> Array.to_list |> List.map M.to_string |> String.concat sep) 
    fin
```

Now we can use `Format.asprintf` to get a string representation of an array.

```
# Format.asprintf 
    "%a" 
    (pp_array 
       (module Int) 
       ~sep:   " " 
       ~start: "[ " 
       ~fin:   " ]" 
       ()) 
    [|1; 2; 3|];;
- : string = "[ 1 2 3 ]"
```

Comment: Properly, two nested loops solve the problem, so thank you for that, but that's not the answer to the question